# Using Web services - could not load type

Tags: web-services, wss-3.0, assembly-references

I have written a bridge between my application and the Sharepoint webservices, to return the data to my project in a useful format. However When any line tries to create a new instance of this webServiceBridge class, it throws this exception.

`Could not load type 'SharepointWeb.ShareList' from assembly 'SharepointWeb, Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

I'm not referencing or using the Sharepoint.dll libraries at the moment as this application is going to be external from Sharepoint Server. For compatibility with WSS3 the sharepoint plugin project (the application I'm writing) is .NET 3.5 but the "configuration tool project" is .NET 4.

All my webFunctions code does is take the XmlNodes returned from the web services and sort it into something usable. In most cases they return `List<MyObject>`

These are the only web methods I am using.

`permissionService.GetPermissionCollection`
`listService.GetList`
`listService.GetListItems`
`listService.GetListCollection`
`siteDataService.GetWeb`

I have tried adding `Microsoft.Sharepoint.dll` as a reference to the project but this did not resolve the issue. But even if it had, I don't understand why it is needed.

Here is what Fuslogvw had to say:
(How ever I will point out that this error appears in FuslogVw *before* the exception causing method is called on and tries to use the web service. Apart from this error it is empty!)

> *** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (19/07/2012 @ 14:38:45) ***
>
> The operation failed. Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.
>
> Assembly manager loaded from: 
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Running under
>   executable  C:\Working\XXXX\Configuration
>   Tool\v2.6.0.3\ConfigurationTool\ConfigurationTool\bin\Debug
>
> \ConfigurationTool.vshost.exe
>   --- A detailed error log follows.
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: User = YYYY\XXXX LOG: DisplayName = msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.6195, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a  (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/Working/XXXX/Configuration
>   Tool/v2.6.0.3/ConfigurationTool/ConfigurationTool/bin/Debug/ LOG:
>   Initial PrivatePath = NULL LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL LOG: Cache Base =
>   NULL LOG: AppName = ConfigurationTool.vshost.exe Calling assembly :
>   (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Working\XXXX\Configuration
>   Tool\v2.6.0.3\ConfigurationTool\ConfigurationTool\bin\Debug
>
> \ConfigurationTool.vshost.exe.Config LOG: Using host configuration
>   file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: msvcm80, Version=8.0.50727.6195,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a LOG: GAC Lookup was
>   unsuccessful. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Working/XXXX/Configuration
>
> Tool/v2.6.0.3/ConfigurationTool/ConfigurationTool/bin/Debug/msvcm80.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Working/XXXX/Configuration
>
> Tool/v2.6.0.3/ConfigurationTool/ConfigurationTool/bin/Debug/msvcm80/msvcm80.DLL. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Working/XXXX/Configuration
>
> Tool/v2.6.0.3/ConfigurationTool/ConfigurationTool/bin/Debug/msvcm80.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/Working/XXXX/Configuration
>
> Tool/v2.6.0.3/ConfigurationTool/ConfigurationTool/bin/Debug/msvcm80/msvcm80.EXE. LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

edit: Added Msvcm80.dll from `%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC80.CRT`

No errors in FuslogVW but exception persists.

This is the full Exception text, not much to go on!

> System.TypeLoadException was caught   Message=Could not load type
>   'SharepointWeb.ShareList' from assembly 'SharepointWeb,
>   Version=2.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
>   Source=Sharepoint   TypeName=SharepointWeb.ShareList   StackTrace:
>          at Sharepoint.FolderBrowser.GrowTree(String siteUrl)
>          at Sharepoint.FolderBrowser..ctor(String siteURL)   InnerException:

Is there anywhere else I can look to find more information that may help me diagnose the cause of this issue?

Comment: Changed question a lot, based on changing circumstances. This is the same error but the original exception text was pointing towards Microsoft.Sharepoint.DLL, which I am not using in any form. (Old info viewable in edit history anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you put your Web Services Dll in bin folder of your Web Application and Gac ?

because Public Key token for your Web Services Dll is coming null so i guess its not in Gac

Comment: Urghh, I literally just needed to sign it and it works from the bin folder.